# Azure aks with virtual nodes and windows os

Tags: azure-aks

I am trying to use virtual nodes with windows os in my AKS cluster.
According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/virtual-nodes-portal#known-limitations it should be possible, and I tried to follow the instructions given in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/virtual-nodes-portal#known-limitations, but with no luck.

Is there any better guide about it?
I wanted to try with the manual set but I miss the information about the VK_RELEASE corresponding to the windows provider.

EDIT

with the "az aks install-connector" I get the error `Error: file "https://github.com/virtual-kubelet/virtual-kubelet/raw/master/charts/virtual-kubelet-for-aks-latest.tgz" not found`, the same if I put the `--chart-url "https://github.com/virtual-kubelet/azure-aci/raw/master/charts/virtual-kubelet-aci-for-aks.tgz"` option

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: with the "az aks install-connector" I get a "till is missing" error, that I interpret as I do not have a complete installation of helm. From the VK_RELEASE point of view, I do not know how to identify the "Windows provider" version (not in a branch nor with a tag)

Comment: why dont you just install tiller?

Comment: I actually have no experience with that, and it is not specified in the tutorial

Comment: I mean, is tiller something I have to install on my cluster or locally? which version of it? is there a compatibility check with the helm version that I have installed? and besides that, it is also written that the command "az aks install-connector" will be shortly become deprecated

Comment: Do you try the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/virtual-nodes-cli#enable-virtual-nodes-addon)?

Comment: @CharlesXu I did try, but it does not say how to specify the operative system.